# installing a program from a .iso on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, iso

I'm trying to install a program from a .iso file that I've downloaded on my ubuntu but I don't know how to do it.

thanks for the help

Comment: What's inside ISO? Is it Windows compatible program?

Comment: Could you please provide more info? What iso file is it? What program are you trying to install from it? What have you tried so far and did not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Open .iso file just by double clicking it and then extract it. So that executable files will be extracted and you can run them.